# Where can I find the Schema for the SDL Tridion UI extensions configuration file

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I downloaded the [HelloWorld Extension for Tridion 2011](http://www.julianwraith.com/2010/10/helloworld-extension-for-tridion-2011/) code to get started with it and everything is working, but I was wondering where I can find more information about the options in the configuration file.

For instance is there a Schema available for the UI extension configuration, in particular for the **cfg:** (http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration), **ext:** (http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions) and **cmenu:** (http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions/ContextMenu) namespaces?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Schemas for all extension namespaces are available on your SDL Tridion CM server under `..\Tridion\web\WebUI\Core\Schemas`, you will find the following files there:

- Configuration.xsd
- ConfigurationMerge.xsd
- ContextMenuExtension.xsd
- Extensions.xsd
- ListExtension.xsd
- TreeExtension.xsd

If you add these in Visual Studio through the XML -> Schemas... menu option (just click the Add... button in the XML Schemas window and select the files from your CM server), you get IntelliSense and XML Document Validation, allowing you to easily experiment with the available options.

Please see [Setting up a SDL Tridion 2011 GUI extension in 8 steps](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/GUIextensionIn8steps.aspx) for more detail about how to get started, this contains more detail than your mentioned HelloWorld example.

Answer (score 8):

You can find the schemas in your Tridion install directory under "\web\WebUI\Core\Schemas".